# Maven exclude resources not working

Tags: java, maven

I googled for my issue but I was not able in finding solution; I'm using maven 3.1.2
I have this profile in my pom.xml

```
<profile>
            <id>test</id>
            <build>
                <finalName>CustomWebAppName</finalName>
                <resources>         
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>environmentConfiguration.properties</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>resourcesTest</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>environmentConfiguration.properties</include>
                        </includes>                     
                    </resource>                     
                </resources>                
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>testDist</outputDirectory>
                            <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>              
            </build>
        </profile>
```

As you can see I'm simply telling maven: when you build the test profile you must ignore the file "environmentConfiguration.properties" in folder src/main/resources and consider the file "environmentConfiguration.properties" in resourcesTest

Well when I launch the command mvn clean install -P test my final web application always contains the "environmentConfiguration.properties" file  located in src/main/resources and doesn't contain the one in resourcesTest
I add to the question my fully [debug log file](https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/126f1a66dd78a89934eab0d299cd398720151105164148/5e3eda71ea67a1d838b9be89936004a920151105164148/0bb5be) generated by maven
Please note this file will be available till November 12nd 2015

Can anybody tell me where I'm wrong?

thank you
Angelo

Comment: The simplest solution is to removed this file from `src/main/resources`. If you need this properties in your tests simply move it to `src/test/resources`....To have different environments the profile path is the wrong one (See here...http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2011/07/29/maven-configuration-for-multipe-environments/)

Comment: i use the src/main/resources in my default profile so i don't want to delete it and i want to use N profile with N resources

Comment: You environment based profile usage is the wrong way...

Answer (score 3):

I don't know exactly whether this is your problem or a typo in your question but there shouldn't be any space between `-P` and `test`

try this instead

```
mvn clean install -Ptest
```

**EDIT**

try to enable filtering

```
<profile>
            <id>test</id>
            <build>
                <finalName>CustomWebAppName</finalName>
                <resources>         
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>environmentConfiguration.properties</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>resourcesTest</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <includes>
                            <include>environmentConfiguration.properties</include>
                        </includes>                     
                    </resource>                     
                </resources>                
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>testDist</outputDirectory>
                            <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>              
            </build>
        </profile>
```

Comment: for a second i was hoping i was wrong in launching command... but sadly it was only a typo problem. Also by using `mvn clean install -Ptest` the result is always the same

Comment: The filtering worked? Filtering has nothing to do with this. Or was the typo the original problem?

Comment: In fact, you're right, that's why I rolled back my answer because apparently it didn't have anything to do with it, the problem might have been another one, but if it worked...

Comment: well i don't know why... I just added filtering and it worked nothing else changed both in pom.xml and in command launch...... sometimes we must not ask to ourself reasons :)